# What is the best way to use a script with applications variable in asp net mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am developing an Asp Net Mvc4 application to a real estate business. In the future this system will be sold to other companies.

The question is, how to create a file to store variables such as company name and other values so I don´t have to type those values in every view I need them?

Is it a good approach to store those values in the database or in a config file?

Answer (score 0):

Generally you'd put things like that (mainly strings) inside a [resource file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fw69ke6f%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) `.resx`. Doing so you can change the string value in just one place (the .resx file) and have it reflected everywhere you use the string as for example the Company Name.

A `.resx` also makes it easy if in the future you decide to provide localized versions of your app. It's just a matter of adding a new `.resx` file with translated values for a given culture/language.